# BeautifulSoup() costructor just get stuck sometimes

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I have a program that crawls a website (~30pages) every several minutes. It has been working fine for the last 1.5 years. However, in this piece of code

```
response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
   ...some code...
htmlPageContent = response
   ...some code...
soup =  BeautifulSoup( htmlPageContent )
```

Strangely, the line

```
soup =  BeautifulSoup( htmlPageContent )
```

Keeps getting stuck. I did not change anything. It just gets stuck when url = different pages (every time on different one). Not consistently and not on particular url. Just getting stuck once in a while (once in ~30 minutes).

What could be the reason?

Comment: you may want to consider looking at the [diagnose](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#diagnose) function

Comment: What do you mean by getting stuck. Does program execution stop?

Comment: Nope. It just enters the costrustor and never gets out of it... as if it is in an infinite loop somewhere inside.

Comment: Have you tried using different parsers see https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#specifying-the-parser-to-use